# gedit fails to open text file via nautilus on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nautilus, gedit

I want to open the file ~/my_file.csv in gedit. With gedit closed, I open nautilus, right click on the file and "Open With" -> gedit. The mouse pointer changes to suggest it is loading, but then nothing happens. The previous works ok with other programs such as emacs and vim. It also works if I have an already active session of gedit, in this case ~/my_file.csv opens in the active session. It opens ok from the terminal if I type

```
gedit ~/my_file.csv
```

It also works if nautilus was launched via sudo. If I check the system logs I can see

```
 -> sudo grep gedit /var/log/syslog | tail -n 3
Mar  1 15:18:54 e111711-lin org.gnome.gedit[4258]: Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Mar  1 15:18:54 e111711-lin org.gnome.gedit[4258]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Mar  1 15:18:54 e111711-lin org.gnome.gedit[4258]: (gedit:3233): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :37
```

I have a similar reproducer from the terminal with

```
 -> DISPLAY=:37 gedit 
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gedit:3404): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :37
```

Any help on fixing the above issue or advice on submitting a bug report would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does `ll ~/my_file.csv` report?

Comment: I don't have anything for `ll`, but assuming you mean `ls -alF`, `-rw-rw-r-- 1 kevmoo kevmoo 819 Mar  1 14:14 ~/my_file.csv`